# Mac Mini 2013 wakes immediately after sleep when USB drive plugged in

Tags: macos, hard-drive, usb, sleep-wake, mac-mini

I have a 2013 mac mini running osx 10.9.3. I used to be able to send the machine to sleep by going to the apple in the menubar and choosing sleep. After a recent update, when I do this the displays turn off, and my usb drives spin down. About 5 seconds later I hear a drive spin up and it immediately wakes from sleep.

I disconnected devices and found that my external usb drives are what are causing the issue. If I remove the usb drives, it will sleep normally. If I eject the drives but do not disconnect them, it will still immediately wake. I know this has only happened within the last month or so, as it used to manually sleep normally.

When I run `syslog | grep -i "wake reason"` I see the following wake reason `kernel[0] <Debug>: Wake reason: XHC1`.

`pmset -g assertions` yields the following output:

```
    Assertion status system-wide:
    BackgroundTask                 0
    PreventDiskIdle                0
    ApplePushServiceTask           0
    UserIsActive                   0
    PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep    0
    InteractivePushServiceTask     0
    PreventSystemSleep             0
    ExternalMedia                  1
    PreventUserIdleSystemSleep     0
    NetworkClientActive            0
    Listed by owning process:
    pid 28(powerd): [0x0000000900000636] 00:15:58 ExternalMedia named: "com.apple.powermanagement.externalmediamounted"
    Kernel Assertions: 0x104=USB,MAGICWAKE
    id=500  level=255 0x4=USB mod=6/10/14, 1:53 PM description=XHC1 owner=AppleUSBXHCI
    id=502  level=255 0x4=USB mod=6/10/14, 6:26 PM description=EHC1 owner=AppleUSBEHCI
    id=504  level=255 0x100=MAGICWAKE mod=6/10/14, 6:33 PM description=en1 owner=en1
```

One drive is a time machine backup, and one has my media. I'd rather not have to unplug the drives before sleeping every time, especially as this seems to be a recent development.